# cannot stop or restart apache in xampp

Tags: apache, xampp

i am using xampp in windows which is running as a service but i am not able to restart apache.
i tried going to the services window and stopping it but eventhough i am running an admin account, the options to start/stop apache is disabled. Thanks..

Comment: This is because more then one instance of the app are running. Go to task manager and end the apache process. Then restart xampp and see if it is working properly

Comment: i tried that. it says access denied eventhough i am logged in as admin